# Obtener variable de un href="#" generado en un for

Tags: php, html

Se puede obtener una variable con el contenido de un href al presionar el hipervinculo, en mi código genero los href con un for el cual me genera bastantes, me gustaría encontrar alguna forma de conseguir la variable href cuando presionan el hipervinculo para así después hacer un div con id=href que me permita reducir el código.

Os adjunto el código por si tenéis alguna duda:

```
  <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= $row['Coach_user']; $i++): ?>
        <div class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              
            Pack de Ejercicios <?= $i ?>
          </button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
              <?php  $directorio2= '../packs/pack'.$i;
                $rowNum2= scandir($directorio2);
                $num2=count($rowNum2);
              ?>
              <?php for ($x = 1; $x <= $num2-2; $x++): ?>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#<?=$i.$x?>">Ejercicio <?= $x ?></a>
               <?php endfor; ?>
          </div>
        </div>
        <?php endfor; ?>  
      </div>
    </div>

<div id=variable obtenida href>contenido</div>
```

Como podéis ver lo quiero obtener seria:#12, #212, por poner ejemplos. Sin la almohadilla seria mejor ya que al hacer id habría que quitarla.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo añadiendo un poco de JavaScript. Una forma de hacerlo es crear una versión en HTML de lo que esperas conseguir con PHP y añadirle la funcionalidad.

#### Ejemplo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <!-- For question: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/367815 -->
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#derdf" onclick="clicked(this.href)">Ejercicio 1</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#sfrdf" onclick="clicked(this.href)">Ejercicio 2</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#djukk" onclick="clicked(this.href)">Ejercicio 3</a>

            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#53a2s" onclick="clicked2('53a2s')">Ejercicio 4</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#d88km" onclick="clicked2('d88km')">Ejercicio 5</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <main>
        <div id="target">Some content</div>
    </main>

    <script>
        let targetId = 'target';

        function clicked(hrefAttr)
        {
            // Obtener valor de href
            const temp = hrefAttr.split('#');
            const cleanValue = temp.pop();
            console.log('href value: ' + cleanValue); // HACK: trace

            // Reemplazar id del div
            replaceId(cleanValue)
        }

        function clicked2(hrefAttrValue)
        {
            // Reemplazar id del div
            replaceId(hrefAttrValue)
        }

        function replaceId(newIdValue)
        {
            const targetElement = document.getElementById(targetId);
            targetElement.setAttribute('id', newIdValue);

            // modifica valor de targetId para obtener el elemento
            // en próximos clicks
            targetId = newIdValue;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Explicación

Como tienes que imprimir cada uno de los enlaces, puedes imprimir al tiempo un `onclick` en los mismos. Te puse dos ejemplos, en uno le pasas a la función receptora `clicked()` el elemento atributo href del que tendrás que sacar el valor limpio del atributo después, o directamente ese valor que estas añadiendo a href, función `clicked2()`.

Finalmente la función `replaceId()` cambia el valor de la ID de tu `div`. He usado una global en este último paso (`targetId`), ya que si el elemento `div` puede obtenerse inicialmente con su ID original *'target'*, al cambiar esta con cada selección, hay que saber cual será cuando volvamos a repetir esta acción.

#### En tu código:

Puedes generar los enlaces así (para usar la función `clicked2()` del ejemplo):

```
<a class="dropdown-item"
    href="#<?=$i.$x?>"
    onclick="clicked2(<?=$i.$x?>)">
    Ejercicio <?= $x ?>
</a>
```

Comment: Entiendo el código pero luego como hago para mostrar el div?Es decir cuando haga <div id="variable href">Contenido</div> como sabrá que al clicar el ejercicio1 la variable sera 11? No quiero hacerlo con if o case porque tengo una lista enorme de ejercicios.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien lo que quieres decir... ¿quieres mostrar una caja diferente con un contenido determinado en función de que enlace pulsas?

Comment: Exacto, según presionan el ejercicio quiero obtener el href de ese ejercicio para así poder ponerlo en un div y mostrar el contenido referente a ese ejercicio. Si es el ejercicio 2 cuando lo cliquen sacar el href que en este caso seria 2 y luego en un div poner como id una variable que contenga el href obtenido en este caso el 2.

Comment: Se me ocurren dos opciones: 1. Imprimir inicialmente todos los *divs* con sus contenidos, ocultarlos todos con *CSS* y mostrar el seleccionado (esto solo lo haría con pocos divs / contenidos). 2. Peticiones asíncronas. En el momento en que seleccionas un enlace solicitas al servidor el contenido relacionado y cargarlo en el div.

Comment: Mi problema aqui en esta en que no se como saber cual se ha seleccionado porque la dirección href no la tengo, como se han generado en el for yo no tengo forma de que cuando alguien presione en un ejercicio sepa cual es. Eso es lo que busco una forma de obtener la dirección href cuando presionan el ejercicio.

Comment: Ok, hipoteticamente tengo guardados en una BD, fichero, etc. 50 ejercicios, que tienen un encabezado y una descripción, eso será su contenido. Debe de tener cada una un identificador único, que sirva para poder recuperarlo y mostrarlo posteriormente. Normalmente tu no sabes cuantos ejercicios hay almacenados, haces una "consulta" y te traes todos los identificadores, contandolos tienes el número de enlaces a mostrar y estos identificadores son los que imprimes en el `href`.

Comment: si, mas o menos, en realidad no tengo una tabla con los datos sino que los tengo guardados por carpetas pero el procedimiento es el mismo. entro en la carpeta cuento las carpetas(que son los ejericicios) y muestro el contenido de cada carpeta. Entonces lo que hago es cuento la cantidad de carpetas que hay y genero esa cantidad de hipervinculos con un contador, carpeta 1 sera el contador uno y el href sera 1 y asi voy haciendo.

Comment: Entonces te recomiendo crear un fichero que indexe esa estructura, puedes revisarla periódicamente o cada vez que vayas a servir la página si creas el contenido manualmente o regenerarlo automáticamente si creas los contenidos mediante PHP. Almacena la información que necesites en él como claves únicas asociadas a las rutas de las carpetas por ejemplo.

Comment: Ya he encontrado una solución haciendo una función con jq que genere una alerta cuando se presiona el hipervinculo y de esa alerta obtengo el href. Gracias de todas formas.